# Music of primes

Tags: soft-question, prime-numbers, music-theory

In http://plus.maths.org/content/music-primes DuSatoy describes the relation between the prime number staircase and harmonics from music. 
So in the article he uses music as an analogy. But I wonder if anyone has tried to produce a sound recording from those frequencies? Or even an image?

Tao also describes a prime sound wave in his presentation, called the "von Mangoldt function" which is noisy at prime number times, and quiet at other times.

chrome-extension://bpmcpldpdmajfigpchkicefoigmkfalc/views/app.html

Even when one plays around with the zeta functions we see:

$\sum_{1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{a+ib}}=0\Rightarrow $

$\sum_{1}^{\infty}\frac{cos(ln(n)b)}{n^{a}}=0$ and $\sum_{1}^{\infty}\frac{sin(ln(n)b)}{n^{a}}=0$.

Musically, when an instrument plays a note, the basic note can be 
represented by A.cos Lt + B.sin Lt. The number L has to do with how 
high the note is (pitch), and A and B have to do with how loud it is; 
t is time.

So from here there are many routes:

1)for $a=\frac{1}{2}$ and $b=14.135$ (non-trivial zero), we could create notes as follows

$\frac{cos(ln(2)14)}{2^{1/2}}+\frac{sin(ln(2)14)}{2^{1/2}}$

$\frac{cos(ln(3)14)}{3^{1/2}}+\frac{sin(ln(3)14)}{3^{1/2}}$

$\cdots$

2)for $a=\frac{1}{2}$ and $b=14.135, 21.022, 25.011...$ (non-trivial zeros), we could create notes as follows for fixed n=2

$\frac{cos(ln(2)14)}{2^{1/2}}+\frac{sin(ln(2)14)}{2^{1/2}}$

$\frac{cos(ln(2)21)}{2^{1/2}}+\frac{sin(ln(2)21)}{21^{1/2}}$

$\frac{cos(ln(2)25)}{2^{1/2}}+\frac{sin(ln(2)25)}{21^{1/2}}$

$\cdots$

Maybe smn can use the above to make a sound recording.

Regards

PS

Here are some links

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i1FqnfrcWA4 (logarithm of primes)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EIpmvTAsaMI (modular arithmetic)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BkCZvhvJdy4 (difference of primes)

Comment: Not that I really understand this question, but perhaps you are looking for something like the sound file at the bottom of this page: http://www.math.ucsb.edu/~stopple/explicit.html?

Comment: that was nice, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I dont really understand the question you are asking here, but a while ago I made this video while working on something else that created something vaguely melodic in a simple way from the prime factorisation of the integers if that is relevant:

http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=l_KEzLb6Cd4